# How to group certain objects in array of objects?

Tags: javascript

```
var list = [{
        'orderSeries': 26342,
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'r8',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'orderSeries': 26342,
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'rs5',
        'year': '2013'
    }, {
        'orderSeries': null,
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'mustang',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'orderSeries': null,
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'fusion',
        'year': '2015'
    }, {
        'orderSeries': null,
        'make': 'kia',
        'model': 'optima',
        'year': '2012'
    }];
```

Is it possible to group the first 2 objects in this array because the orderSeries value is the same, and the rest of the objects to not be grouped by orderSeries property because the value for those is null?

and to get a format of the array like this when its grouped:

```
var list = [{
        'orderSeries': 26342,
        'make': 'audi',
        cars: [
            { 'model': 'r8', 'year': '2012'},
            {'model': 'rs5', 'year': '2013'}
        ]
    }, 
    {
        'orderSeries': null,
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'mustang',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'orderSeries': null,
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'fusion',
        'year': '2015'
    }, {
        'orderSeries': null,
        'make': 'kia',
        'model': 'optima',
        'year': '2012'
    }]
```

Comment: Yes, but for consistency, for were you have only 1, I would still use `cars`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use just forEach and fill new list with some modifications

[image: Edit elegant-mcclintock-c9h77]

```
const list = [{
  'orderSeries': 26342,
  'make': 'audi',
  'model': 'r8',
  'year': '2012'
}, {
  'orderSeries': 26342,
  'make': 'audi',
  'model': 'rs5',
  'year': '2013'
}, {
  'orderSeries': null,
  'make': 'ford',
  'model': 'mustang',
  'year': '2012'
}, {
  'orderSeries': null,
  'make': 'ford',
  'model': 'fusion',
  'year': '2015'
}, {
  'orderSeries': null,
  'make': 'kia',
  'model': 'optima',
  'year': '2012'
}];

const groupedList = [];

list.forEach(item => {
  if (!item.orderSeries) {
    groupedList.push(item);
  } else {
    const existingGroup = groupedList.find(i => i.orderSeries === item.orderSeries);

    if (existingGroup) {
      existingGroup.cars.push({ model: item.model, year: item.year });
    } else {
      groupedList.push({
        orderSeries: item.orderSeries,
        make: item.make,
        cars: [
          { model: item.model, year: item.year }
        ]
      });
    }
  }
});

console.log(groupedList);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over `list` while updating two arrays, one for orders with `orderSeries` and another without it
- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) again, iterate over the first list with `orderSeries` while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to group the items by the `orderSeries`
- The resulting list will include the grouped list and the ones without `orderSeries`

```js
const list = [ { 'orderSeries': 26342, 'make': 'audi', 'model': 'r8', 'year': '2012' }, { 'orderSeries': 26342, 'make': 'audi', 'model': 'rs5', 'year': '2013' }, { 'orderSeries': null, 'make': 'ford', 'model': 'mustang', 'year': '2012' }, { 'orderSeries': null, 'make': 'ford', 'model': 'fusion', 'year': '2015' }, { 'orderSeries': null, 'make': 'kia', 'model': 'optima', 'year': '2012'  }];

const [ordersWithSeries, ordersWithoutSeries] = list.reduce(([a, b], order) => 
  order.orderSeries ? [[...a, order], b] : [a, [...b, order]]
, [[], []]);

const groupedOrdersBySeries = [...
  ordersWithSeries.reduce((orderSeriesMap, { orderSeries, make, model, year }) => {
    const order = orderSeriesMap.get(orderSeries);
    if(!order) {
      orderSeriesMap.set(orderSeries, { orderSeries, make, cars: [{ model, year }] });
    } else {
      order.cars.push({ model, year });
    }
    return orderSeriesMap;
  }, new Map)
  .values()
];

const res = [...groupedOrdersBySeries, ...ordersWithoutSeries ];

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply manipulate original data one by one using for loop.

```js
const list = [{
    orderSeries: 26342,
    make: "audi",
    model: "r8",
    year: "2012"
  },
  {
    orderSeries: 26342,
    make: "audi",
    model: "rs5",
    year: "2013"
  },
  {
    orderSeries: null,
    make: "ford",
    model: "mustang",
    year: "2012"
  },
  {
    orderSeries: null,
    make: "ford",
    model: "fusion",
    year: "2015"
  },
  {
    orderSeries: null,
    make: "kia",
    model: "optima",
    year: "2012"
  }
];

let mergeIndexes = [];
let newList = [];

const placeholder = {
  orderSeries: null,
  make: "",
  cars: []
};

for (let i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {

  // continue if current index is already merge with the previous
  if (mergeIndexes.includes(i.toString())) continue;
  const item = list[i];
  const filter = list.filter((i) => i.orderSeries === item.orderSeries);
  if (filter.length && Boolean(item.orderSeries)) {
    placeholder.orderSeries = filter[0].orderSeries;
    placeholder.make = filter[0].make;
    placeholder.cars = filter.reduce(
      (prev, curr) => [...prev, {
        model: curr.model,
        year: curr.year
      }], []
    );
    newList = [...newList, placeholder];
    // to keep track of the indexes that are already merge
    mergeIndexes = [...mergeIndexes, ...Object.keys(filter)];
  } else {
    newList = [...newList, item];
  }
}
console.log(newList);
```